# Wordpress -multi urls for the same site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a Wordpress site (v4.2.2) with domain name www.example.com and need to point a second local domain variant www.example.co.za to the same site.

have tried many suggestions from modifying wp-config.php, index.php and .htaccess, but failed to get it to work.

For index.php

```
<?  // Check Domain and Change to Proper Spelling if Necessary
$our_server = "example.com";    
$our_http = "http://www.example.com";   
if  ( isset($HTTP_HOST) && !eregi($our_server, $HTTP_HOST)) {
        header("location: $our_http$REQUEST_URI");      
        exit;   
} 
?>
```

For .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)example\.co.za$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,NE]
```

I will appreaciate some guidance on this topic on how to redirect www.example.co.za to www.example.com

Comment: Where is your website hosted? Do you have shared hosting such as godaddy, or are you on a VPS with the ability to modify the Apache config?

Comment: using shared hosting, the .co.za site is a pointing domain

Comment: Some shared hosting companies allow you to set up multiple domains. Note that you will need to change the Apache config unless you are happy with a standard redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have multiple domains with a single Wordpress install, you need to do a couple of things.

You need to add a DNS `A record` and point the 2nd domain to your IP address of your main domain.

You need to add this domain as an alias in Apache `ServerAlias *.example.co.za`

Then edit your `WP config` to look at the HTTP_HOST so it will be dynamic instead of using a hardcoded domain.

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Using .htaccess rules you have now to redirect is not going to give you another domain with the same content. That will just redirect to the main domain.

Comment: to add an Apache ServerAlias like  *.example.co.za - is this what hosting company must do?

Comment: If your shared hosting already recognizes your 2nd domain you can skip this part. Or usually they have a control panel where you can add other domains. If you can't figure that part out, ask the host to add it as an Alias domain otherwise if it's already set that way, you can skip that step.